# Java RMI client tries to load implementation instead of interface

Tags: java, rmi, rpc

I have a problem with a RMI clients class loading behaviour:

My RMI Server side application exports a `ISessionFactory` object with a single method:

```
ISessionToken createSession(String username, String password) throw RemoteException;
```

The `ISessionFactory` extends `Remote`, `ISessionToken` is `Serializeable`.

I have three projects: Client, Server (contains `*Impl`) and Facade (contains `ISession*`).

The server starts up fine and I can lookup the `ISessionFactory`. For test purposes I added a `doSomething` method which prints out a string via System.out at the server side, this also works fine. A call to `createSession()` however does not, but gives the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmiserver.SessionTokenImpl (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:198)
   at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
   at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createSession(Unknown Source)
   at rmiclient.Client.main(Client.java:14)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
   rmiserver.SessionTokenImpl (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
   at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:396)
   at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:186)
   at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
   at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
   at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:214)
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:326)
   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:175)
   ... 4 more
```

I understand that without export of `ISessionToken` it will be serialized and passed to the client, so I have to validate every session token passed to the server.

What I don't understand is that the client feels the need to load the Impl class of the token. As far as I am concerned it should be doing fine by knowing the interface? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that without export of ISessionToken it will be serialized and passed to the client.

Correct.

> What I don't understand is that the client feels the need to load the Impl class of the token.

Because you didn't export it, so it will be serialized and passed to the client. You just said so yourself.

> As far as I am concerned it should be doing fine by knowing the interface?

Only if you export it. Even then, the client actually receives a stub which *implements* the interface. You can't just send around an interface without something that implements it.

> What am I missing?

You didn't export it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the impl would not be needed if the interface was known.
So, either I export the ISessionToken and its methods are executed on the server, or I see the the SessionTokenImpl classes are available both to the server and the client (Either via project setup or via RMI class loading)?

Comment: Just export it. It's a remote interface: surely that was your intention? Otherwise remove `Remote` and the `Impl` part of the name and make it serializable.

Comment: `ISessionToken` is not remote, just serializeable, thats what I intended (to export the session token to the user). I just did not want to expose some API of the token (like a generate method) which let to the exception.